# I've had a problem with this python problem return outside function and even though I do align the function to fix it it still exist, why?

Tags: python-3.x

The error which shows is the return outside function from this, how would I fix this `class Solution(object):

```
def isHappy(self,n):
    result = 0
    while n>0:

        r = num % 10
        result = result + r * r
        num = num//10
    return result

seen = set()
while sqsum(n) not in seen:
    sum1 = sqsum(n)
if sum1 == 1:
    return True
else:
    seen.add(sum1)
    n = sum1
    return False`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that computes the sum of digits is called isHappy, but you refer to `sqsum` later. Also, I proper reference function in the class Solution.

Here is my modification of your solution of the LeetCode(?) problem:

```
class Solution(object):
    def sqsum(self, n: int):
        result = 0
        while n>0:
            r = num % 10
            result += r * r
            num = num//10
        return result

    def isHappy(self, n: int):
        if n < 1:
            return False

        seen = set([1]) # stop if we run into the loop or see 1
        while n not in seen:
            n = self.sqsum(n)
            seen.add(n)

        # we are here if we encounter 1 or start running repetitive sequence
        return n == 1
```